# Several questions about Pentaho Mondrian

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I'm new and trying out Pentaho Mondrian for my company's proof of concept work.

We are dealing with very large scale of data (billions of rows), running on Greenplum.

However, I've met a couple of roadblocks and would appreciate if the questions below could be answered?

1. Is there any tool out there that could *assist* in transforming our current DB schema to Mondrian's OLAP schema?
2. Given the example MDX query below:

```
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Visits]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {
        HEAD(
            DESCENDANTS(
                [Location],
                [Location].[Segment Name],
                AFTER
            ),
            3
        )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Location Metrics]
WHERE (
    [Location].[Segment Name].[Bla Bla Bla],
    [Location].[Period].[Weekly],
    [Location].[Location Type].[Website],
    [Location].[Industry Name].[Ferrari Owners]
)
```

In the log files of Tomcat, the generated SQL query does not have the WHERE clause nor the LIMIT 3.  So my question is, does these filtering and limiting/offset happen in DB or in OLAP server layer?  If its the latter, what about tables with billions of rows?

Answer (score 0):

The Head method is not natively pushed to SQL by Mondrian. Try using [TopCount / BottomCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx)

Mondrian will also push to SQL the Filter() method, when the predicate is simple enough to be expressed by simple arithmetic, as opposed to MDX tree operations, like Dimension.CurrentMember.

Comment: `SELECT
    [Measures].[Total Visits] ON COLUMNS,
    TOPCOUNT(
        [Industry Name].MEMBERS,
        100
    )
    ON ROWS
FROM [Location Metrics]
`
---
`select "location_metrics"."industry_name" as "c0", sum("location_metrics"."visits") as "m0"
from "olappoc_us"."location_metrics" as "location_metrics"
group by "c0"
`

Hi Luc, see the MDX above, translates to the SQL. Still does not hav e the LIMIT clause despite using TOPCOUNT.  Is there any documentation on what goes to SQL, and what not?

Comment: Try setting these properties for Mondrian. Create a file called mondrian.properties at the root of your classpath and it should get picked up. These properties will allow you to turn on all 'native' optimizations.

mondrian.native.crossjoin.enable=true
mondrian.native.topcount.enable=true
mondrian.native.filter.enable=true
mondrian.native.nonempty.enable=true
mondrian.rolap.groupingsets.enable=true

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use any tool then you can use Pentaho Schema Workbench. It is very good open source tool for creating olap schema and you can publish it into Pentaho BI Server and visualize it and also perform operation like slicing, roll-up, roll-down.

Comment: Thanks, but Schema Workbench is basically a GUI tool to generate the XML schema (correct me if I'm wrong).  What we would like is to have a tool that can understand our schema automatically and distinguish the dimensions and measures and write the XML directly.

Moreover, we tried to launch Workbench with our database and it basically hangs the process, seems like our dataset is too huge for workbench.